# Angular nx-daterangepicker-material get date

Tags: angular

I am using ngx-daterangepicker-material to pick date . I need to know how can see the pick date in console ?

```
<input type="text" ngxDaterangepickerMd [(ngModel)]="selected" (change)="getClaims()" [locale]="{applyLabel: 'ok', format: 'DD-MMMM-YY'}" class="form-control"/>

if(this.selected){
  console.log(this.selected); // need to show date in DD-MMMM-YY Format
}
```

I need to show date in console in (format will be DD-MMMM-YY)

[image]

Comment: What is it showing if it's not showing date? Post the output of console log

Comment: update attachment in question its showing in arrays but i need to show date in DD-MMMM-YY In this format

Answer (score 0):

As you can see both of your startDate and endDate are of a type [Moment](https://momentjs.com/docs/)

Therefore you could easily format the date to your needs

```
if(this.selected){
  console.log(this.selected.endDate.format("DD-MMMM-YY"); // need to show date in DD-MMMM-YY Format
}
```

You can do the same with `startDate`